# html - Twitter bootstrap resize a column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with class `.table .table-striped .table-bordered` 

now when I try to change the width of my second column it doesnt resize.  I've tried width: 50%    
and inline styling still no luck.

Comment: Please post your code and consider creating a test case using jsfiddle, codepen or similar.

Comment: dont use inline!!!!!! dirty, dirty.... as above, test case or link to actual site would help, no code = no answer im afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override it in your CSS like this:

```
.table tr td:nth-child(2) {width:50%;}
```

See example: http://bootply.com/60325

Comment: this worked.. sorry for posting no code... Im new to jsfiddle
dunno how things work yet.... Thank you